# Install a plugin in Bitnami Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, plugins, redmine, bitnami

I want to install a plugin in Redmine:

I unziped the plugin and copied it into the plugins directory. Then I run the command bundle install but I get the following 
error:

*Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
Could not find json-1.8.6 in any of the sources*

I did 'gem install json1.8.6' and I looked at the Gemfile.lock and the json is there, but still getting the same error.
I looked at the Extensions section in my Redmine administration but I still get the message "No data to display"

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you include a link to the specific plugin?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Please provide more information about the platform you are using and the plugin you are trying to install when asking here. Generally, in order to install a plugin in Redmine, you will need to copy the plugin into into `installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins`, and then run the `bundle install` commands inside the htdocs folder. https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/redmine/#how-to-install-a-plugin-on-redmine Please remember to use the Bitnami Console if you used the Bitnami Native Installer

Comment: I am using Bitnami Redmine 3.3.3 stable.  The plugin I was trying to install is : https://www.redmine.org/plugins/users_performance